# Eclipse find and replace

Tags: eclipse

Is there a quick way to replace this:

```
public static String ACCESSDENIED = Resources.strings.getString(Resources.ACCESS_DENIED);
```

with:

```
public stattic String getAccessDenied(){
 return Resources.strings.getString(Resources.ACCESS_DENIED);
}
```

I need to replace all static references to getters in about 100 variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by using the find and replace with regex expressions.

```
Find: = (.+);
Replace: () { return $1; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use *right-click --> Refactor --> Encapsulate Field... --> (new getter created)*, and everything is done automagically (and its a bulletproof solution).

You can also verify the results in a *Preview* window.